# Android Studio (Java) button to open activity unresponsive after switching tabs

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I have used the template Buttom Navigation activity on android studio which have 3 menus, which are home, dashboard and navigation. I placed the button in home fragment, and it worked initially but when I switched menus and went back to the home, and pressed the button it wont work anymore.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;

Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

    // This is the code for the button to open activity
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.emergency_button);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendReport.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: please post relavant code here.

Comment: Hi @JohnJoe, sorry for the late reply. what do you mean by relevant code? I have posted the code above

Comment: why you placing button in `MainActivity`? You should place in home fragment.

Comment: Ohhh okay I'll do that thank you